# rdd.saveAsTextFile executes on driver or workers inside foreachRDD.

Tags: apache-spark, streaming

Below is my code snippet. I have DStream which I am trying to save it to HDFS. Just wanted to know efficient way with compression.

```
    pairedDStream.foreachRDD { rdd =>        
    val time = Calendar.getInstance.getTimeInMillis;
    val textOutputFolder = outputDir + "/output-" + time
    if (args.length == 4) {
      val compressionCodec = args(3)
      rdd.saveAsTextFile(textOutputFolder, CommonUtils.getCompressionCodec(compressionCodec))
    } else {
      rdd.saveAsTextFile(textOutputFolder, CommonUtils.getCompressionCodec(null))
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

`rdd.saveAsTextFile` is executed on worker nodes, in fact all rdd operations are executed parallelly inside `dstream.foreachRDD`. Spark documentation mention we should use this dstream operation for pushing the data in each RDD to an external system.

> **foreachRDD(func):** The most generic output operator that applies a
>   function, func, to each RDD generated from the stream. This function
>   should push the data in each RDD to an external system, such as saving
>   the RDD to files, or writing it over the network to a database. Note
>   that the function func is executed in the driver process running the
>   streaming application, and will usually have RDD actions in it that
>   will force the computation of the streaming RDDs.

[Design Patterns for using foreachRDD](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#design-patterns-for-using-foreachrdd) section also clearly states dstream.foreachRDD is a powerful primitive that allows data to be sent out to external systems. You can further read this section to know how to optimize operations on RDD in a dstream.

Hope this helps!